# Why are my grater than and less than if statements not working?

Tags: visual-c++

The beginning of my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "give two values: ";
int val1 = 0;
int val2 = 0;   
int low = 0;
int high = 0;
```

The section below (up to the break) should differentiate between the highest and 
Lowest values for val1 and val2, but Val2 always equals high, and val1 
always equals low when I run the program. It seems that the greater than and less that if statements that I have created are not working.

```
    while (cin >> val1 >> val2) {
    if (val1 == val2) {
        cout << "the values are equal\n";
        high = val1;
        low = val2 ;
    }
    if (val1 > val2) {
        high = val1;
        low = val2;

    }
     else if (val1 < val2); {
        high = val2;
        low = val1;
    }
    break;
  }
```

This is the last part of my code and it gives the user info about the numbers
they picked

```
    cout << "Value one and two added together is: " << val1 + val2 << "\n"
            << "Value one and two subtracted is: " << val1 - val2 << "\n"
                 << "value one and two multiplyed is: " << val1*val2 << "\n"
                 << "value one and two divided is: " << val1 / val2 << "\n"
<< "The lowest value is:" << low << " and the highest value is:" << high;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Drop the semicolon between the paren and the opening brace. As written, the very last block of assignments is executing unconditionally.

Comment: Also, you are breaking out of the loop on the first iteration, no matter what values were entered. Your loop ain't actually looping.